# Adding meta data to an attachment post

Tags: post-meta, attachments

I want to add a meta data to my attachment posts, so I can get them in order by meta value later. That meta value would be `'price'`.

So I thought this could work:

I have this args:

```
$args = array(
'order'          => 'ASC',
'post_type'      => 'attachment',
'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_status'    => null,
'numberposts'    => -1,
);
```

Then I get posts (attachment posts) with `$att_posts = get_posts($args);`

Then I would like to add to each attachment post, a meta data called `'price'`, which value I get by `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true)['price'];`.

So I thought this would do the work to add the meta data:

```
foreach( $att_posts as $att ){

  wp_update_attachment_metadata(
    $att->ID, 
    array( "price" => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true )['price'] ) )
  );

}
```

So i declared other args again but this time to order by `'meta_value_num'`, with meta key `'price'`.

But it didn't work.

Any body knows a simple way to make that possible? Any tips?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is all my code to get attachment images ordered by `'meta_key'` `'price'`.

```
$args = array(
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'post_status'    => null,
  'numberposts'    => -1,
);


$att_posts = get_posts($args);

if ($att_posts) {
  foreach( $att_posts as $att ) {
    wp_update_attachment_metadata(
      $att->ID,
      array( 'price' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', true ) )
    );
  }
}


$args = array(
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key'       => 'price',
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'post_status'    => null,
  'numberposts'    => -1,
);


$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
  foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo '<a href=' . $surl . '/' . $post->post_name. '>' .
    wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail_large' ) . '</a>';
  }
} else {
  echo '<a href='.$surl.'/' . $post->post_name . '>' .
  '<div class=\'thumbnail-small-img-search\'></div>' . '</a>';
}
```

But still doesn't work.

Another way of asking is: How can I add meta data to attachment posts. And later, get the attachment posts ordered by this meta data called `'price'`.

The objective of this is to display a paged list of posts with images ordered by price from cheapest to expensive.

This would be invoked by a submit button to one page of the website.

Comment: If this truly is all your code, it is really wrong. I have deleted my previous answer as a result. You need to better explain what you are trying to do. Do you want to retrieve the current post, then get all attachments for the post, then update the attachments' price metadata to be the same as that for the post, and then output all attachments ordered by price? And if so, how would the prices be different, given what you have? Clarification definitely needed; flagged.

Comment: Hi. I want to add a meta data to my attachment posts, so I can get them in order by meta value later. That meta value would be 'price'

Comment: what is the problem with the question? It´s simple, I just want a way to get attachment posts ordered by a meta value 'price'. That I tried to add

Comment: What is the problem with the question?

Comment: Your edit rendered my answer completely incorrect. Your subsequent edits have made the question understandable, but you need to provide the context in which this code is being used. (Is it on a template? In a plugin? In functions.php? When is it invoked?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So since `attachments` are post types, you should be able to assign them `postmeta` like any other post type.

Using the `update_post_meta` function should get you where you need to be.

`update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'price', $price );`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Then run your query based on a meta key.

```
$args = array(
'order'          => 'ASC',

'post_type'      => 'attachment',
'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_status'    => null,
'numberposts'    => -1,

'meta_key'       => 'price',
);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters